# Deploy VBA Cell Reference in Array Formula

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to do a couple things with this subroutine but can't get VBA to execute the .FormulaArray function.

1. Create a named range using offset & lastrow function
2. Use cell references to insert into the array formula

--

```
Sub namedrange()
    Dim firstrow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ColToLetter, absolute, Title, mc, mc1

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
    absolute = ActiveCell.Address
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    firstrow = ActiveCell.Row
    ColLetter = Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, 1)
    ActiveSheet.Range(ColLetter & firstrow & ":" & ColLetter & LastRow).Name = Range(ColLetter & "1").Value
    Title = Range(ColLetter & "1").Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    mc = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address
    mc = Mid(mc, 2, 3)
    mc1 = Replace(mc, "$", "")

    ActiveCell.FormulaArray= "=IF(ROWS(mc & "":"" & mc1)>SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Title<>"""",MATCH(Title,Title,0)),ROW(Title)-ROW(absolute)+1),1)),"""",INDEX(Title,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Title<>"""",MATCH(Title,Title,0)),ROW(Title)-ROW(absolute)+1),ROW(Title)-ROW(absolute)+1),ROWS(mc & "":"" & mc1))))"
End Sub
```

The formula bar shows what the vba function is outputting, which is not what I want. I don't know why it won't output the references I've created like mc should be "$A$2" not "mc".

Also when I try to execute the FormulaArray code I get a runtime error 1004 "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class"

Comment: In your statement `Rows(mc & "":"" & mc1)` Your double quotes get counted as two empty strings. True using `CHR(34) to get quotes in your string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.FormulaArray` content has some typos. Here's how it should look like (assuming all the above code is fine):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaArray= "=IF(ROWS(" & mc & ":" & mc1 & ")>SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Title<>" & chr(34) & chr(34) & ",MATCH(Title,Title,0)),ROW(Title)-ROW(absolute)+1),1))," & chr(34) & chr(34) & ",INDEX(Title,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Title<>" & chr(34) & chr(34) & ",MATCH(Title,Title,0)),ROW(Title)-ROW(absolute)+1),ROW(Title)-ROW(absolute)+1),ROWS(" & mc & ":" & mc1 & "))))"
```

In general, remember that if you want the value of a variable to be printed into a string, you cannot write `"a=mc+3"` but rather `a = " & mc & "+3"`.

Comment: Ahhh that's why it wasn't working, i'll have to try that & see how it works. Thank you all.

Comment: Okay so how would I print the value of the other references in a string?

    IF(&Title&<>


I have "Title" & "absolute" as references which I can't print

Comment: @Zebra the logic is always the same. If you want the value of the variable, you always have to nest it as I showed you above: `"IF(" & Title & "<>"`

Comment: A trick that I always use: position your cursor in the point in which you want the value to appear, then type `"`, `&`, `&`, `"`. Position your cursor in between of the two `&` and type your variable.

Comment: @Zebra if it works, please accept the answer. It will tell other users that this is the solution to your problem